# A question regarding a fragment of Robinson Arithmetic

Tags: lo.logic

In his answer to the following mathoverflow question, [The (un)decidability of Robinson Arithmetic without multiplication](https://mathoverflow.net/q/177047/1946), Emil Jerabek proved that the following fragment:

1. $\forall$x(Sx$\neq$0)
2. $\forall$x$\forall$y(Sx=Sy $\Rightarrow$ x=y)
3. $\forall$x(x$\neq$0 $\Rightarrow$ ($\exists$y)(x=Sy)
4. $\forall$x(x+0=x)
5. $\forall$x$\forall$y (x+Sy)=S(x+y)

"with '0' as the sole constant and 'S' [successor] and '+' as the built-in function signs...and whose deductive system is your favourite classical first-order logic with identity." (Quote from Peter Smith, the OP in question.)

is undecidable, and in fact hereditarily undecidable.

Question:  What would be an example of a true but undecidable well-formed formula definable in the language of this fragment?

Comment: In your language you can say that every element is even or odd. This is true in the non-negative integers under addition but false for the set of polynomials with non-negative leading coefficients (under addition, with successor defined in the obvious way.)

Comment: I added a link to the previous question. Also, @SJR, why not post your comment as an answer?

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to the linked answer, $\forall x,y\,(x+y=y+x)$ works as an example. The model in my answer does not even satisfy $\forall x\,(x+1=1+x)$ (that is, $\forall x\,(S(0)+x=S(x))$.) Even simpler, I see no reason the theory should prove $\forall x\,(0+x=x)$, though this would require a different model.

Comment: I also sense there is some confusion going on, since the question uses the word “undecidable” in two different senses, almost adjacent to each other. So let me stress that the linked question concerned the *algorithmic* undecidability of the Robinson arithmetic without multiplication, not its incompleteness (which should be obvious, as the theory does not include the Presburger division axioms such as the one mentioned by SJR).

Comment: Oh, of course: the theory does not prove $\forall x\,(0+x=x)$, because full Robinson arithmetic does not.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  If you would interpret '$+$' as '$\frown$' and add to the fragment of Robinson arithmetic under consideration the following axiom $\forall$x $\forall$y $\exists$z $\exists$w (x+y=z+w), the resulting theory would prove commutativity and $\forall$x (0+x=x).

Comment: ??? That axiom is a tautology (take $x$ for $z$ and $y$ for $w$).

Comment: Oh, and if you meant $\forall x,y\,\exists z,w\,(x+z=w+y)$, that still doesn't imply commutativity or $0+x=x$. For instance, if $M$ is any model of (1)-(5) (e.g., violating $0+x=x$), let $M'$ be a model with domain $M\cup\{\infty\}$, where $a+\infty=\infty+a=\infty$ for all elements $a$, and $S(\infty)=\infty$. Then $M'$ is a model of (1)-(5) and of your extra axiom. The axiom also holds in the model in my linked answer.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  My interest is in models where '$+$' is interpreted as concatenation.   Here is what I am attempting to do:  consider an arbitrary string of |' s, say, |||||.  It , through concatenation, can be expressed several different ways (e.g.  |$\frown$||||, ||||$\frown$|, |||$\frown$||, etc.).  If one allows for '0' to be interpreted as the empty string '$\epsilon$', it seems to me that $\epsilon$$\frown$| = |$\frown$$\epsilon$ (if one deems $\epsilon$$\frown$| to be meaningless one could always add this as an axiom--is this your point?).  In any case let me know if there is a

Comment: (cont.) 'proper' first-order way to express this fact as an axiom.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, whatever happened to rules of substitution in logic where variables can be substituted for other variables?  In $\forall$x $\forall$y $\exists$z $\exists$w(x$\frown$y=z$\frown$w) is there some reason one cannot substitute 'y' for 'z' and 'x' for 'w' (since you took "$x$ for $z$ and $y$ for $w$)?  In the case of ||||| (since x,y,z,and w take such strings as values), why can't x=|, y=||||, z=|||, and w=||? Certainly those values satisfy my original axiom-- would my original axiom be deemed a tautology then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turning what SJR wrote to an answer: the true but undecidable sentence is:

$$ \forall x((\exists y(x=y+y))\lor(\exists y(x=S(y+y)))). $$

Comment: Thanks (also to SJR who had the original idea).  Question: How do you show that the consistency of this fragment of Robinson Arithmetic cannot be proven in this fragment of Robinson Arithmetic (seeing as how it cannot represent the recursive functions)?

Comment: I am highly suspect that such a weak system even has a proof predicate.